# Fedora xrandr cannot turn on external DP1(DisplayPort) monitor

Tags: fedora, monitor, xrandr

My laptop is T420 and My OS is fedora 19, kernel is 3.2
I have a VGA and DP(DisplayPort).  VGA works well. 
But DP does not work well.
DP works well in windows system.

It can not detect DP when I use "xrand -q" to query .

[xiuxia@Mars ~]$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3520 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
   1600x900       60.0*+
   1024x768       60.0
   800x600        60.3     56.2
   640x480        59.9
VGA1 connected 1920x1080+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0
   1600x900       60.0
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0
   1280x800       59.8
   1152x864       75.0
   1280x720       60.0
   1024x768       75.1     60.0
   832x624        74.6
   800x600        75.0     60.3
   640x480        75.0     60.0
   720x400        70.1

I've googled , but I can not solve my problem? 
Do I lack drivers, then what's the driver name ?
I frustrated about this, hope some nice people can help me.

Comment: I had similar issue with f22, had to activate the nvedia card and use dp. There seems to be regression introduced bug tracked at - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1224470